Delay added automatically for polling call by Jmeter version 5.5
My Jmeter script has parellel controller with two polling calls, one polling call will be triggered every 10 seconds and 30 seconds respectively.
My Jmeter script has parellel controller with two polling calls
Inside polling call
During the beginning of the test, each polling call triggered in respective to 10 & 30 seconds respectively. As the test gradually proceed further, Jmeter adding delay to trigger the each polling call triggered at interval from 10 to 20 seconds and from 30 to 40 seconds automatically. The server response will be always ~10 & 30 seconds. Even if there is no think time between polling, could not identity the issue why the Jmeter added delay.
The following logs shows how jmeter added the delay for the click from beginning to end.
The polling happens exactly every 30 seconds in the beginning of the test
enter image description here
The polling happens every ~40 seconds at the end of the test. why Jmeter added the delay gradually in the entire test.
enter image description here
Please note the script is working good with single user.
The polling has to happen every 10 & 30 seconds from jmeter script.


JMeter waits for the completion of previous Sampler before starting the new one
If you have a Timer for creating the delay the Timer is being executed before each Sampler in its scope
If you want to run 2 requests at different rate/frequency/throughput - you should rather put them under separate Thread Groups due to point 1 otherwise the whole execution speed would be the speed of the slowest Sampler
If you're unsure regarding which element is causing the delay try increasing JMeter logging verbosity to DEBUG and check jmeter.log file, it might be the case you will be able to figure out the reason from there

